# MVC4 Post/RedirectToAction / refresh redirect issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

What works..

1. execute a redirect after a save to DB.. which works fine.

   ```
   return RedirectToAction("Index", new {id = appt.CourseExamApptID});
   ```
2. The Index view displays my confirmation message and the user can now go through the process again if they want. If user clicks back, the app does what a GET is supposed todo and gives a pretty error message. The URL displayed is /reserve, which was the POST action that I redirected from.

The problem:

If at this point the user clicks refresh, the app executes the the "/reserve" url, which takes the user to the Reserve-GET in my controller..This is a problem because my Reserve-GET is expecting parameters through a step by step process..My apps errors out with null params but I DONT want to user to go here to begin with..

Question:

Can the target of the redirect be displayed in the URL instead or the origin? Will this prevent user from redirecting back to my Reserve-GET upon refresh?

Comment: Might be a better solution but you could make those parameters optional, and if they are not set in the controller do a conditional redirect (to an error page or whatnot).... or you might be able to overload the action method and just redirect for a parameterless action method

Comment: optional parameters and a condition did the trick, thanks steve.